# Loading a saved cell array not as struct

Tags: matlab

I have one question related to loading cell array in Matlab. I have read the similar questions but none of them solve my problem! 
I have a cell array with size {400*350} in my workspace. I saved this cell array as usual:

```
save ('myoutput.mat','cell_array');
```

Then I tried to reload this mat file. I used:

```
3D_coordinates = load ('myoutput.mat');
```

when this mat file is loaded in my workspace it converted to a struct file with size 1*1. I have to click on it and inside of the structure file there is one cell. when I click on that cell my whole cell array is appeared! it means my whole cell array is in a cell inside of a structure variable! then I assumed that by converting structure to cell I could access to my whole array.

```
cell_array = struct2cell(3D_coordinates);
```

but nothing changed! my cell_array size still 1*1 and inside of it, there is on cell, when I click on that cell , whole my cell array will be appeared !!! 
I want to access to my whole cell array in my workspace directly like before saving! How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
coordinates = load('myoutput.mat');
cell_array = coordinates.cell_array
```

where `coordinates` is the `struct` you get after loading the .mat-file and `cell_array` is the name of the included cell array.

**Be aware that variable names in Matlab cannot start with a number!**

---

You can save a line by using `importdata` instead of `load` and get directly to the cell array:

```
cell_array = importdata('myoutput.mat')
```

Comment: THX. your second suggestion cell_array = importdata('myoutput.mat') works find and it is exactly that I needed. THX